# nginx: php file extension does not work with try_files

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to make a download script, that catches all requests to /files/ and  forces a download. The script fully works, and downloads any file I throw at it. The problem is that when I try to pass a file with a .php extension through try_files, the following nginx config messes up:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name _;

    root /var/www/localhost/public_html/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.txt;


  location /files/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /.thedownloadscript.php?file=$uri;
    }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /public_html$fastcgi_script_name;    

    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  ssl_certificate /var/www/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /var/www/server.key;
}
```

> /files/file.txt downloads the file.
>
> /files/script.php throws a 404.

Both paths should be passed to the download script, but aren't.

I have tried removing the try_files from the "location ~ .php$" block, but that makes it output *"No input file specified"*.

I hope somebody can help me out here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/901761/nginx-redirect-to-a-php-file-with-try-files-if-required-php-file-not-found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any regex location block takes precedence over a prefix location block at the same level, unless the latter uses the `^~` modifier.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Try:

```
location ^~ /files/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /.thedownloadscript.php?file=$uri;
}
```

Note that the `location ^~ /files/` block is a prefix location (and not a regex location).

Answer (score 1):

According to nginx best practices you should isolate regexp locations:

```
location / {
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
    }
}

location /files/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /.thedownloadscript.php?file=$uri;
}
```